# Rename windows service

Tags: windows, service

Is there a way to rename a windows service?  Not the display name, mind you, the actual name.  I can't seem to edit the value in enum\root to be what I want, and there ought to be an easier way, I just can't find it!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I'd imagine it'd break whatever process relied on that service...

Answer (score 10):

IIRC the following worked for me (once):

*This is nothing I ever would recommend doing*

#### This is what I did

1. open regedit
2. navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`
3. Look at the keys in the treestructure inside the left pane and select the service you would like to rename
4. Rename the key using the `Rename` entry in the Context-Menu
5. If there is a subkey named `enum` delete it. It will get recreated the next time the service starts.
6. You might want to change the Subkey `DisplayName` according to the new service name
7. Reboot the machine for changes to take effect
8. Pray it did not screw things up

Answer (score 3):

Use SC.exe Create to create a new service in Windows with the paramaters that you want.  Then use SC.exe Delete to delete the old service.

SC is a command line program built in to Windows that is used for communicating with the Service Control Manager and services.

Comment: I disencourage you to answer old posts without adding some value add, and even not really answering the question. The question is about to rename a service, and create a new one and delete the previous could be used as a comment but seems to be a poor answer.

Comment: I don't aggree with alphamikevictor. The info is useful for the question.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions on ENUM/Root are quite strict, besides I believe it's a dynamic area controlled by Windows.  The place you want to be looking is HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services.

Comment: Yeah, I tried editing that, but the services menu just declared that a registry key was not found :^)

Comment: You don't say what your service is doing, but you could capture the existing service's parametes as a .REG file, remove the existing service and create a new one using SC.EXE.  Then edit the .REG to rename the "key" entries ([HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\<name>\...], plus remove any system generated stuff (password hash, etc).  Re-import and reboot.  Alternatively, manually add the display name, dependencies, Etc.  Of course, I'd test on a VM first ;-)